# ¿Por qué se llama "Santa Fe", no "Fe Santa"?

Tags: gramática, adjetivos, nombres-propios, orden-de-palabras

Pensé qué el adjetivo va siempre antes del sustantivo, excepto en casos de cantidad ('muchas casas', 'diez perros', etc.) Recientemente me he dado cuenta de que "Santa Fe" no se refiere a un santo, y no puedo entender por qué el adjetivo está primero.

Comment: ¡Bienvenido a [Spanish.SE]! Hay infinidad de [poblaciones llamadas "Santa Fe"](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Santa_Fe#Localidades_y_divisiones_administrativas). ¿Te refieres a alguna en concreto o a todas en general? ¿O a otra cosa?

Answer (score 6):

Si hablas de la ciudad en Nuevo México, el nombre completo sí es de un santo — San Francisco de Asís.  Pero bueno...

El adjetivo no siempre va después del sustantivo.  Hay varias razones por las que un adjetivo puede ir antes, pero en este caso la diferencia es que «fe santa» referiría a una fe que, por casualidad, es santa.  Pero al hablar de «santa fe», estamos hablando de una fe que se identifica principalmente por su santidad.

Comment: Hubiera pensado que la ciudad cuyo nombre proviene de San Francisco de Asís es San Francisco, CA...

Answer (score 5):

En este caso creo que se trata más de algo que se ha dicho así por tradición desde tiempos inmemoriales. Véanse los siguientes casos extraídos del CORDE (negritas mías):

> *E el dicho sennor rey ganandola, entregola a la **santa fe catolica** de Ihesu Cristo e de la su bendita madre Santa Maria, nuestra abogada.*
>
> Anónimo, "Castigos e documentos para bien vivir ordenados por el rey Sancho IV", 1293 (España).
>
> ---
>
> *Mas tanto fizo y estonces aquell obispo Germano; que por la su predicacion tornaron muchos a la fe de ihesu xpristo en Costantinopla. & de si ell emperador Justino mando a todos los obispos xpristianos que fiziessen las eglesias. & que fuessen mantenidas & seruidas por **clerigos de la santa fe**.*
>
> Alfonso X, "Estoria de Espanna que fizo el muy noble rey don Alfonsso...", c1270 (España).
>
> ---
>
> *¡Señor Ihesu Christo, de piedat lleno! ¿Do estavas tu aquel dia que la çibdat de Merida salio **de la santa fe**?*
>
> Anónimo, "Crónica del moro Rasis", c1300-1344 (España).

Es decir, cuando se habla de la "santa fe católica", el orden de las palabras es casi siempre ese, y es algo que se lleva escribiendo así desde hace siglos. Lo que no quita para que, de vez en cuando, se encuentre escrito al revés:

> *E asý quiere que se salven teniendo **la fe santa católica** verdadera e cunpliendo los sus mandamientos [...].*

En todo caso, el número de casos de "fe santa" con respecto a los de "santa fe" son muy reducidos (los casos en el CORDE son de aproximadamente 1 contra 20). Es por tanto normal que cuando se fundaran los pueblos (o lo que fuese) se usara el término "Santa Fe" dado que era como la "coletilla" que se usaba.

Comment: No solo «santa fe», también tenemos Santa Biblia, Santa Compaña, santa madre, santo varón y muchos ejemplos más. Parece que este adjetivo tienen tendencia a ir delante del sustantivo.

Comment: @blonfu sin olvidarnos de la "Santa Inquisición"... que ya les vale...

Comment: Perhaps we need a list of examples where santo/santa goes after the noun like _semana santa_ to see what the common feature is?

Comment: @mdewey That's a very good example that shows that we are defining a specific week: not all weeks are holy, only the Holy Week is.

Answer (score 1):

Me parece que el caso de "santa fe" (o "Santa Fe") no es muy diferente del de otros adjetivos que se anteponen a sustantivos ([Is adjective-noun-adjective the normal pattern?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/21533/is-adjective-noun-adjective-the-normal-pattern/21534#21534))

Los adjetivos antepuestos suelen ser subjetivos y descriptivos, mientras que los pospuestos suelen ser objetivos y definitorios. En la frase nominal "santa fe", "santa" es casi inherente a "fe", y por eso su ubicación normal es precediendo al sustantivo. Veamos, por contraste, la frase de quien quiera descalificar esa virtud tildándola de "fe estúpida" o "fe irracional".

Cuando la ubicación habitual es la antepuesta, la posición detrás del sustantivo puede sonar hasta enfática: "fe santa", "Virgen santa", "Padre santo". En este último caso, ocurre además que la frase "Santo Padre" suele reservarse para el Papa, y entonces "Padre santo" se utilizará más comúnmente para referirse a Dios Padre.